# Duplicates in repeater are not allowed error being thrown by angular

Tags: angularjs

Since my angular version upgrade to 1.2.0, updating some of the scope objects keeps throwing me the "Duplicates in repeater" error inconsistently. This might have to do with the $$hashKeys maintained by angular that are being retained on the server side(which shouldn't happen) and angular trying to assign new hashKeys to the unassigned objects. So does angular have inbuilt support to strip $$hashkeys from data objects before sending them to the server?. I am using the http service to make my server requests. Does http.post do anything internally to strip $$hashKeys off the the data object passed through it? 
From what I know, angular.toJson can do the job of removing $$hashKeys but I'm not sure whether I should do that explicitly.

Comment: Properties starting with `$` are stripped automatically when you send data to the server.

Comment: Is that so?. So then I guess it has to do with stringifying the js object which I am doing before it is sent to the server.

Comment: I see. An object is stringified automatically per default, so there's no need to do it yourself. Provided you need nothing fancy.

Comment: what would come under the 'fancy' definition?

Comment: strip properties ;) `JSON.stringify` gives you control over how an object is represented as string. You could serialize a boolean value to 'YES' and 'NO', a child object as a single value, omit certain properties or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error when trying to ng-repeat on some collection, you should know that angular in it's newer versions doesnt easily allow iteration over primitve collections (like an array of numbers) but on comlex object collections (like an array of user specified object e.g: students)
But if you insist on iterating over a primitive type array you could use the "track by" syntax:

```
  <div ng-repeat='item in [1,2,2,3,4,3] track by $index'>
       {{item}}
   </div>
```